# in ios how to create geo location based alarm?

Tags: iphone

I want to create an alarm that will remind me based on any particular place. whenever I reached that place the alarm should start beeping.

Please help someone I tried to search over internet but still not get

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CoreLocation framework for what you want to achieve.

Here is an Apple example of CoreLocation

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LocateMe/index.html

Here is what you can try :

Set a reminder - While setting remainder get the current location & save the latitude + longitude of that location.

When user moves from one location to another, CoreLocation will be returning significant location change notification.

Check for the latitude + longitude & see if it matches with the reminder you have saved.

If YES alarm user or else leave it as it is.

Hope it Helps !!!

Comment: Thanx arun, can u please share code, how to create alarm based on longitude and latitude

Answer (score 0):

There are apps already that do that, for example, this one:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-on-place/id1234840835?mt=8

But if for some reason you want to create it yourself, you should set regions using the core location framework in the location you want the alarm to be fired and in the handle of the enter of the region you can send a local notification or start playing a sound.